# Data Access Layer in c#

Tags: c#, data-access-layer

I want to create a data access layer in c# for first time. So I read and used tutorials ... now I have a simple code, but this code doesn't work...

for ex: for my delete query...

this is delete web method:

```
[WebMethod]
public void DeleteMethod(string DBName, string tableName, string attributes, string values)
{
    DBName = DAL.dataAccess.DBname;
    tName = DAL.dataAccess.tName;
    DAL.dataAccess.Delete(attributes, values); 
}
```

this method pass elements to `dataAccess` Class and the class create query and connect to my data base. the `dataAccess` class code for delete query:

```
public static string DBname { get;set; }

public static string tableName { get;set; }

public static void Delete(string field, string condition)
{
    connect = new SqlConnection(string.Format(_conString, DBname));
    adp.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand();
    adp.SelectCommand.Connection = connect;

    adp.SelectCommand.CommandText = "delete  from " + tName + " where " + field + " = " + condition ;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    connect.Open();
    adp.Fill(ds);
    connect.Close();
}
```

at first I used `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` instead of `adp.Fill(ds);`, but this doesn't work and get error. so I changed my code to this...

> Now I get this error at `adp.Fill(ds);`: "Incorrect syntax near the
>   keyword 'where'."

What is my code problems??

Comment: And what is your error? You should use `ExecuteNonQuery();`.

Comment: edit my post...

Comment: Using inline query in c# code is a bad practice which can easily lead to sql injections. Use Stored procedure instead !

Comment: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'." means your resulting query is invalid. Check the result by logging it or by breakpoint if you are able to. It can be caused by the data type of the field not matching.

Comment: Watch your resultant query "adp.SelectCommand.CommandText" and you will know what exact query is getting fired

Comment: Also, I think you're exposing too much access in your web service. It's not good to accept tables, fields and conditions to build your dynamic queries. You'd be better off using a repository instead.

Comment: @ Vandita I always use stored procedure. but I want  write a reusable layer, so I don't have a fix DB

Comment: @Ephraim : I guess its because of tableName. but why?

Comment: @sali : Try using adp.DeleteCommand instead of  adp.SelectCommand

Comment: Your design is too dynamic. This prevents you from utilizing SqlCommandParameters thus leaving you vulnerable to Sql injections. Who would want to expose all of their databases in their web services? You should limit it to a scope, this is where the repository pattern comes into play. Search for it. Understand it. Though it will require more coding, it is more secured. If you want to push your design, just check the resulting query on your `adp.SelectCommand.CommandText` and use `adp.ExecuteNonQuery();` instead.

Comment: whats the value of 'tName' (I think tName should be tableName as well), also what are the values of 'field' and 'condition'

Comment: @Ephraim: thanks so much. search that. but my plan was: get this information (like DB name) from a xaml form, and just a programmer can fix DB name in this form. Isn't it secure?

Comment: @ozidom : tNeme is table name. field: a field in our table(column name). and condition is the value of column. For ex. if  "id = 10" delete rows with this condition

Answer (score 0):

You should use an approach more like below - where you are correctly USING the connections and commands:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection((string.Format(_conString, DBname))
{
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.CommandText = "delete  from " + tName + " where " + field +  " = " + condition ; 
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

see here for more details on why you need to use using : [https://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlconnection]

Comment: This is the correct usage of disposable objects such as `SqlConnection` but OP's error is different.

Comment: I do this first. but it doesn't work... I keep trying... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your delete method:-

You can hard code the connection string instead of reading from a config file.
    Also, for me the table is Employee, for you it could be your table name.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        tableName = "Employee";
        string condition = "'User4'";
        Delete("Name", condition);
    }

public static void Delete(string field, string condition)
    {
        string _conString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];

        using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(_conString))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();

            adp.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand();
            adp.SelectCommand.Connection = connect;

            adp.SelectCommand.CommandText = "delete  from " + tableName + " where " + field + " = " + condition;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            connect.Open();
            adp.Fill(ds);
            connect.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I know this work. but it isn't reusable. if I want to change my target table, I have to change table name here! but thanks so much :)

Comment: You can set the tableName property first and then use the code... I have updated the method Just check if it works for you.